# Get data to Bootstrap modal to update data

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to edit/ update data that show in my page. The edit/ update data should done in modal. Below is code that I tried and it didn't work.
I tried lots of methods to done this. But not succeeded. IF anyone can help on this it would be very grateful. Thank you.

```
<?php 
$query1=mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM food_menu WHERE status='1' AND category='Breakfast'" );
?>
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card border-dark">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title"><b>Breakfast Menu</b></h3>
        <?php
        while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
          $id=$row1['id'];
          $name=$row1['name'];
          $details=$row1['details'];
          $category=$row1['category'];
          $price=$row1['price'];
          $image=$row1['image'];
          ?> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="zoom">
                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="rounded float-left img-thumbnail" alt="Food Image">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div hidden><?php echo $id; ?></div>
              <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5>
              <h7><?php echo $details; ?></h7><br>
              <h7><b>Rs. <?php echo $price; ?></b></h7><br>
              <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editbtn" name="edit" id="edit" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><span class="icon text-white-100">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
              </span>UPDATE</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      <?php  } ?> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add" id="add">Add New</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



<!-- End of Page Content -->
```

My Modal is below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editmodal" name="editmodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post">
                  <input type="text" name="fid" name="fid" >
                  <input type="text" name="food_name" id="food_name">
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript Used.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.editbtn').on('click', function(){
       $('#editmodal').modal('show');
       var ids = $(this).attr('data-id');
       $(".modal-body #fid").val( ids );
       $(".modal-body #food_name").val( ids );
     });
    });
    </script>
```

When I click update button the modal is shown but data is not showing the modal.

Comment: try `var ids=$(this).data('id');`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I'll try it. I my coding right?

Comment: BTW, I just noticed where you assign the values, you only need the # id ref. Also, #fid has no id attribute, you gave it name twice

Comment: I didn't get it. I really want to populate data that related to the id.

Comment: As you mention the the 'id' is comes to the modal. Then how can I get other data related to that id?

Comment: make a data attribute for each piece of information you want!  `data-id="<?=$id?>" data-food-name="<?=$food_name?>"`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. As I mention earlier, I'm getting the value now. Can I pass that value to a PHP variable inside the modal? I want to code some If Else statement from that value. I have no idea about this.

Comment: Ah, now I see the root of the problem. You’re missing the big picture.  While you are writing everything on the server, php is only executed on the server; it’s purpose is to send html to the client (browser). Once the browser receives it, the only way to communicate back to php (on the server) is to submit a form or submit via ajax. So to answer your question, there is no such thing as a php variable inside the modal. Once the page is delivered to the client, it’s all javascript. That is why the way you have coded it is such a good idea (php logic separated as much as possible from html)